# How to write numbers relative to an arrow while making a directed graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I need to display a directed graph on a LaTeX document, it should look like this:
[image: Graph]

but I can't find how to write the numbers above, below, right o left to a line or an arrow, can someone give a helping hand?
Thanks in advancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch on the `auto` option, this is as easy as saying

```
\draw[red] (H) -- node{5} (B);
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=2em,
execute at begin node=$,execute at end node=$},auto]
 \path[nodes=circ] 
  (-2,2) node[draw=blue] (H){H} (0,2) node (B) {B} (2,2) node (C) {C}
  (-2,0) node (I){I} (0,0) node[fill=red] (F) {F} (2,0) node (D) {D}
  (-2,-2) node (G){G} (0,-2) node (A) {A} (2,-2) node[fill=cyan] (E) {E};
 \draw[red] (H) -- node{5} (B);
 \draw[green] (F) -- node{1} (D);
 \draw[thick] (I) -- node{6} (G);
 \draw[red,->] (D) -- node[black]{4} (A);
 \draw (H) -- node{2} (I) -- node{3} (B) -- node{4} (C) -- node{3} (D)
  -- node{6} (B) -- node{5} (F) -- node{7} (I) -- node{8} (A)
  -- node{3} (F) 
  (G) -- node{4} (A) -- node{2} (E) -- node{4} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other options include the use of `edge`s, possibly with the `quotes` library. IMHO the benefits from using `quotes` are sometimes overstated.

Comment: Thank you!, this really helps