# Cannot draw arrows in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have the following code for a graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[blueringnode/.style={circle, draw=blue!100, fill=white, thick, minimum size = 7mm},
redfillnode/.style={circle, draw=black!100, fill=red!100, thick, minimum size = 7mm},
commonnode/.style={circle, draw=black!100, fill=white, thick, minimum size = 7mm},
redringgreenfillnode/.style={circle, draw=red!100, fill=green!60, thick, minimum size = 7mm},
blackringcyanfillnode/.style={circle, draw=black!100, fill=cyan!60, thick, minimum size = 7mm}, auto
]
\node[redfillnode](maintopic){\textit{F}};
\node[commonnode](topcircle)[above=of maintopic]{\textit{B}};
\node[commonnode](leftcircle)[left=of maintopic]{\textit{I}};
\node[redringgreenfillnode](bottomcircle)[below=of maintopic]{\textit{A}};
\node[commonnode](rightcircle)[right=of maintopic]{\textit{D}};
\node[commonnode](toprightcircle)[right=of topcircle]{\textit{C}};
\node[blueringnode](topleftcircle)[left=of topcircle]{\textit{H}};
\node[commonnode](bottomleftcircle)[left=of bottomcircle]{\textit{G}};
\node[blackringcyanfillnode](bottomrightcircle)[right=of bottomcircle]{\textit{E}};
\draw[-](leftcircle.east)--node{$7$}(maintopic.west);
\draw[-](topcircle.south)--(maintopic.north);
\draw[-](bottomcircle.north)--(maintopic.south);
\draw[-](leftcircle)--(topcircle);
\draw[-](topcircle)--(rightcircle);
\draw[-](bottomcircle)--(leftcircle);
\draw[-](bottomcircle)--(bottomleftcircle);
\draw[-](bottomcircle)--(bottomrightcircle);
\draw[-](rightcircle)--(bottomrightcircle);
\draw[-](rightcircle)--(toprightcircle);
\draw[-](topcircle)--(toprightcircle);
\draw[-](leftcircle)--(topleftcircle);
\draw[-,red](topleftcircle)--(topcircle);
\draw[-,line width=0.5mm](leftcircle)--(bottomleftcircle);
\draw[-,green](maintopic)--(rightcircle);
\draw[->,magenta](rightcircle)--(bottomcircle);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get an error on the last line (\draw->,magenta--(bottomcircle);), I intended to get an arrow starting from the right node to the bottom-center node; this is an illustration of what I wanted to get:

[image: intended result]

but instead I get this:

[image: reality]

any idea of why this is happening? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With your code, after completing it to compilable small document, I got your first image but without edge labels. For them I suggest to use `quotes` TikZ library.

**Edit:**
Use a common style for all nodes, rename to `tl`, `tm` and `tr` for the top row of nodes and on similar way for other rows, and drawn lines in the loops (as suggest  Schrödinger's cat in his comment below) make your code much shorter:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
V/.style args = {#1/#2}{circle, draw=#1, thick, fill=#2, minimum size=7mm, font=\itshape},
   V/.default = {black/none},
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=3pt, auto},
                        ]
\node[V=blue/none]      (tl)    {H}; % top left
\node[V,right=of tl]    (tm)    {B};
\node[V,right=of tm]    (tr)    {C};
%
\node[V,below=of tl]    (ml)    {I};
\node[V=black/red,
        right=of ml]    (mm)    {F};
\node[V,right=of mm]    (mr)    {D};
%
\node[V,below=of ml]    (bl)    {G};
\node[V=red/green,
        right=of bl]    (bm)    {A};
\node[V=black/cyan,
        right=of bm]    (br)    {E}; % bottom right
% the lines are drawn in a loop
\draw   (tl) edge[red,"$5$"] (tm) 
        (tm) to["$4$"] (tr)    
             to["$3$"]       (mr) to["$4$"] (br)
             to["$2$"]       (bm) to["$4$"] (bl)    
             edge[line width=.5mm, "$6$"]   (ml) 
        (ml) to["$2$"]       (tl)
        %
        (ml) to["$7$"]       (mm) to["$5$"] (tm)    
             to["$3$" ']     (ml)
        %
        (tm) to["$6$"]       (mr) edge[green,"$1$"] (mm)
        (mm) to["$3$" ']     (bm) to["$8$"] (ml)
        %
        (mr) edge[->,thick,magenta,"$4$"]   (bm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510481/194703) for a much shorter code yielding practically the same. You are duplicating *many* nodes for no reason.  e.g. instead of `\draw   (leftcircle)    to["$7$"]   (maintopic) 
        (maintopic)     to["$5$"]   (topcircle)` `\draw   (leftcircle)    to["$7$"]   (maintopic)   to["$5$"]   (topcircle)` is sufficient.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, ups, this question is than duplicate ... I just little bit clean-up OP code . You can suggest to close this question as duplicate.